# Why won't Pry run in Heroku's console?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, pry

**My goal is to use Pry as the console for my Rails app, both locally and on my staging server.** But I can't get it to work on Heroku.

I'm following [these](https://github.com/pry/pry/wiki/Setting-up-Rails-or-Heroku-to-use-Pry#wiki-heroku) instructions to get Heroku to use Pry as the console for my Rails app. When I run `heroku run console pry`, my console prints `Running console pry attached to terminal... up, run.1` and then exits. When I run `heroku console pry` it just says `main` and then exits.

**Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong?**

Here's what I've done so far:

1. In my **Gemfile** I've added the lines:
   `gem 'pry'`
   `gem 'pry-rails'`
2. I've created a file called **pry** which contains:
   `#!/usr/bin/env ruby`
   `require 'pry'`
   `pry`
3. I added the following to all the files in **config/environments**:
   `silence_warnings do`
   `begin`
   `require 'pry'`
   `IRB = Pry`
   `rescue LoadError`
   `end`
   `end`
4. run `bundle install`
5. run `git push staging master`

Comment: I think putting it the project root (the same directory as `Gemfile` et al) is correct. As @JohnBachir mentions make sure you also have `gem 'pry'` in your Gemfile and that you've run `bundle install` and then added `pry`, `Gemfile`, and `Gemfile.lock` to your repository before pushing it to Heroku.

Comment: @Jordan, I had already done that; just updated question to reflect it.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I am the one who developed the method for Heroku and Pry but you brought up an interesting case that I didn't think about since I mostly deploy with Sinatra and EM and build my own helpers and such.  Either way:

To use Pry with Heroku while having a Rails app you just need to add pry-rails and pry to your gemfile (as a normal Gem) and then `bundle install` and then `git [commit|push]` and run `heroku run console` on Cedar stack.  Step 3 of what you did where you adjusted *config/environments* does not and should not be done so please revert that change if you can.  After you do that and remove the pry script from the root of your app (well you don't necessarily need to do the latter) Pry will load with your Rails properly.

Comment: Uh-oh. I'm on `bamboo-mri-1.9.2` not `ceder`. Does it only work on `ceder`?

Comment: @theWillCole You should be able to use it on Bamboo as well, just adapt the console launch to the one required by your stack which I believe for Bamboo is just `heroku console` for Bamboo stack.

Comment: I upgraded to the "thin" server and heroku's "cedar" stack. Somewhere along the line pry started working. I'm not entirely sure what the problem was, but this answer works for me now.

Answer (score 3):

I've just used the instructions at https://github.com/pry/pry/wiki/Setting-up-Rails-or-Heroku-to-use-Pry to set it up, pry file goes in the root of your project. Commit and push to Heroku - I'm using the Cedar stack.

Effect a console session to `heroku run console pry` - I did find that I did then need to execute `pry` to be dropped into a pry prompt but it then worked as I'd expect.

UPDATE: Just to be clear, I added pry to Gemfile and created the pry file as instructed. Is your problem that you are locking pry in your gemfile to dev/test - are you running your apps on Heroku in those environments? Hence why you're getting undefined methods?

Comment: I removed the :groups => [ :development, :test ] from my Gemfile. I no longer get the undefined method error, but the console still exits as soon as I start it.

Comment: For future visitors to this question, as the instructions now stand in 2017,  just run `heroku run console`.

Answer (score 0):

You probably have to list it in your bundler Gemfile.

Comment: Had already done that but forgot to mention it in the question. Any other thoughts?