# Getting rails error when using Spaceship::Tunes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, fastlane

In a rails app I am running:

```
54    def itunes_all_apps
55      begin
56        Spaceship::Tunes.login(params[:itunes_username], params[:itunes_password])
57        apps = Spaceship::Tunes::Application.all
58        render json: apps.to_json, status: 200
59      rescue => e
60        render json: {error: e}.to_json, status: 500
61      end
62    end
```

It returns a status 500 error with no other information every time.

However, if I change this around slightly, for example getting teams (note, from Spaceship, not Spaceship::Tunes) this works fine:

```
def itunes_all_apps
  begin
    spaceship = Spaceship.login(params[:itunes_username], params[:itunes_password])
    teams = spaceship.teams
    render json: teams.to_json, status: 200
  rescue => e
    render json: {error: e}.to_json, status: 500
  end
end
```

I'm not using any fast file or or config or anything. Just passing in a username and password via an api call and trying to get a response back. I'm new to rails so it may be my implementation of the Spaceship examples provided.

Using spaceship 0.36.1 gem (the latest)

I've pored through the docs to no avail.  Grasping for any leads on what I'm doing wrong.

http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/spaceship/Spaceship/Tunes

https://github.com/fastlane/fastlane/blob/master/spaceship/docs/iTunesConnect.md

Someone suggested I run these two commands in irb, which I did, and they worked perfect!

```
Spaceship::Tunes.login('myAppleId', 'myPassword')
Spaceship::Tunes::Application.all
```

So it's not an iTunes account problem or credentials problem (because it works in irb), routes problem (because I ran both rails methods above with same route), or params problem (because I ran both rails methods above with same param names).

I really appreciate any suggestions. Thanks.

**Edit:**

Commenting out begin, rescue, and rending the error, the stack trace is as follows:

```
2016-10-24T17:47:34.974650+00:00 app[web.1]: Started POST "/api/v1/users/13/itunes_all_apps" for 162.237.102.13 at 2016-10-24 17:47:34 +0000
2016-10-24T17:47:34.977478+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by Api::V1::UsersController#itunes_all_apps as JSON
2016-10-24T17:47:34.977521+00:00 app[web.1]:   Parameters: {"itunes_username"=>"myCorrectUsername", "itunes_password"=>"[FILTERED]", "team_id"=>"myCorrectTeamId", "id"=>"13", "user"=>{}}
2016-10-24T17:47:35.629629+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=POST path="/api/v1/users/13/itunes_all_apps" host=myHerokuApp.herokuapp.com request_id=002d906d-354e-4633-8b54-71aa5181e3a7 fwd="161.237.102.13" dyno=web.1 connect=2ms service=657ms status=500 bytes=259
2016-10-24T17:47:35.619597+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 642ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
2016-10-24T17:47:35.620430+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2016-10-24T17:47:35.620432+00:00 app[web.1]: IOError (not opened for reading):
2016-10-24T17:47:35.620434+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2016-10-24T17:47:35.620433+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/controllers/api/v1/users_controller.rb:58:in `itunes_all_apps'
```

Comment: Seems that the `render json: {error: e, status: 500}.to_json` should be written like `render json: {error: e}.to_json, status: 500`, though I'm not sure if the `to_json` call is needed. Rails might infer that automatically.

Comment: @Magnuss Thanks, I've updated my `render` method though it did not have an affect.

Comment: When you say "It returns a status 500..", that would imply that an exception is happening, what kind of error is it? Can you put `puts e.to_s` right after `rescue => e` and read the server log?

Comment: @Magnuss Thanks, I haven't been sure how to troubleshoot this.  I did so now and in the log it says `not opened for reading`.

Comment: Ok, I'm going to need a bit more info. Can you remove the whole `rescue` block and let it fail and add the whole exception stack with backtrace from the server log to your question?

Comment: @Magnuss I removed the rescue and added the stack trace as you requested.

Comment: can you do `require json` in `Rails::Initializer`. This might be related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/683989/how-do-you-deal-with-the-conflict-between-activesupportjson-and-the-json-gem

Comment: can you install pry rails see here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8901549/why-wont-pry-run-in-herokus-console . after that add line `binding.pry ` after `rescue => e`   and before `render json: {error: e}.to_json, status: 500`, when the error occurs you will have access to console, then try to examine apps and also e and post what you get

Comment: Another thing - does `Spaceship::Tunes::Application.all.to_json` in irb work as well?

Comment: `Spaceship::Tunes::Application.all.to_json` interestingly does work in irb but not in my project.  Yet, `all.to_s` seems to work in both irb and my project.  Any thought why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that `Spaceship::Fastlane::Application` does not implement `as_json` method and the default `as_json` touches some IO object, which cannot be represented as json.

My suggestion would be to create JSON serializer. You could use [active_model-serializer](https://github.com/rails-api/active_model_serializers), but if you do not want to create a dependency just for one object, then you can create your own serializer.

```
class SpaceshipApplicationSerializer
  attr_reader :spaceship_applications

  def initialize(spaceship_applications)
    @spaceship_applications = spaceship_applications
  end

  def as_json(options = {})
    spaceship_applications.each_with_object([]) do |spaceship_application, memo|
      memo << object_as_json(spaceship_application)
    end
  end

  def object_as_json(object)
    attributes.each_with_object({}) do |attribute, memo|
      memo[attribute] = object.send(attribute)
    end
  end

  def attributes
    [
      :apple_id,
      :name,
      :vendor_id,
      :bundle_id,
      :last_modified,
      :issues_count,
      :app_icon_preview_url
    ]
  end
end
```

# In your controller

```
def itunes_all_apps
  begin
    Spaceship::Tunes.login(params[:itunes_username], params[:itunes_password])
    apps = Spaceship::Tunes::Application.all
    render json: SpaceshipApplicationSerializer.new(apps).to_json, status: 200
  rescue => e
    render json: {error: e}.to_json, status: 500
  end
end
```

**EDIT:**

Yes, the classes return an array, but the actual objects in array don't play nicely with json. It's hard to say if the problem is with the library - on one hand `Spaceship::Tunes::Application` not returning a proper json representation is a missing feature, but if the `to_json` raises an exception (a method the class responds to) - then I would say that is a bug.

Creating your own serializer to build json representation the way you want it - is a common pattern.

Comment: I will try your serializer.  Also, how did you conclude it did not implement `as_json`?  For my own future knowledge, because from the docs as far as I could tell all apps returns an array and all teams returns an array, so why wouldn't both implement json?  Or is it something wrong with the library?  Incredible thanks for your time.

Comment: Updated my answer